# Which nonnegative matrices have exact nonnegative matrix factors of smaller dimensionality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factorization, nonnegative-matrices

The nonnegative matrix 
$V = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1  \end{array} \right)$
has nonnegative matrix factors $W = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1  \\ 1  \end{array} \right)$ and $H = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1  \end{array} \right)$, i.e. $V=WH$. The identity matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \end{array} \right)$, on the other hand, has no exact nonnegative factors of smaller dimensionality.

In general, which nonnegative matrices have nonnegative factors, and which do not?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact" factors? The identity is the product of two transposition matrices, so obviously you exclude these.

Comment: Sorry to have to ask, but can you please point out to me which matrices multiply to get the identity matrix? The NMF solver I'm using (in R from CRAN) doesn't find factors for identity.

Comment: Put the ones in the lower left and upper right. Square it. Voilà, the identity.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I meant to specify that the condition that the dimensionality of $W$ and $H$ have to be smaller than $V$. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the notation in the question, I think the actual concept that the OP is looking for is: [Nonnegative rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_rank_%28linear_algebra%29)

(Also, googling for "Nonnegative rank" will bring up several useful links).

Finally, this recent paper [on Nonnegative matrix factorization](http://www.ece.umn.edu/~nikos/06630130.pdf) covers what seems to be known about the desired (typically **low rank**) factorizations.